# Why do I have to check for length === 0 to restart the slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm following the Codecademy "Make an interactive website" course. I don't have an error, but I had a question about something I don't understand: the if-statement used in a slide thing thing thing.

```
if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        };
```

This if-statement is for that after the last slide it will go to the first slide.
Why is it `nextSlide.length === 0`?

jQuery:

```
var main = function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        };

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if` statement is there to do a check as to if there is a slide after the current slide or if it should revert to the first slide.

`nextSlide.length` will return a number to represent if the next slide exists, else it will return 0.

`.length` API Docs: [Here](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

Answer (score 3):

If your question is why `===` instead of `==`

This ensures that the variables being compared are of the same `type`

More reading here: [SO Question === vs ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: @Darren-Sweetney Oh sorry, I wasn't clear enough... :D I meant why it's 0, I made 0 bold but the system blocked it... But actually I also didn't understand that thing of yours :) So thank you anyways I'll watch that == vs ===.

Answer (score 1):

That checks if there is a next slide. If it is **0** it means there is no next slide.
In JavaScript, the length of emptiness is 0.